# Why is \p{Lu} matching lowercase letters?

Tags: regex, powershell, character-class

`Lu` is supposed to represent `Letter, Uppercase`, however I am getting
unexpected results

```
PS > 'Hello World' -replace '\p{Lu}', 'Z'
ZZZZZ ZZZZZ
```

As can be seen, `Lu` is replacing upper and lower characters.

[§ Regular Expression Category](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/20bw873z#CategoryOrBlock)

[§ Supported Categories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/20bw873z#SupportedUnicodeGeneralCategories)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `-creplace`. [`-replace` is case-insensitive](http://www.regular-expressions.info/powershell.html):

```
PS > 'Hello World' -creplace '\p{Lu}', 'Z'
Zello Zorld
```